# Using SimpleSAML with Yii2 - Multiple Autoload Issue

Tags: php, single-sign-on, composer-php, yii2, autoloader

As the title suggests, i've currently got a working Yii2 portal, which we're upgrading to enable use of SSO with SAML.

For handling the authentication we're using SimpleSAML, which is sat outside of the web root as the SimpleSAML documentation instructs.

The problem being, both Yii2 and SimpleSAML have their own instance of composer, along with its own autoloader.  So i'm having problems finding a way to successfully require the SimpleSAML composer autoloader from within Yii2, which is already requiring it's own composer autoloader.

Can anyone offer any guidance on this?

Comment: I found SimpleSAML to be overkill if you are creating a simple Service Provider. Perhaps consider using something smaller like [lightsaml](https://github.com/aerialship/lightsaml) - it works nicely with composer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, rather than a problem with the require, it was a problem with calling the function the correct way in Yii2, so using the example on the SimpleSAML website, within Yii2 add a slash to whichever function you need to use, as so:

```
    $as = new \SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix the conflict issue patching the autoloaders.

I recommend you to read:

- http://alanstorm.com/laravel_composer_autoloading
- https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3003
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration

Or take a look on this easy php saml toolkit: https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml